# Deactivate preview on right click

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm on Windows (7 and XP, 64bit and 32bit). When I right click on a file, it opens inside the editor (which is handy sometimes, but mostly annoying, e.g. for pdf, etc.). 
Is there an option to stop sublime text from opening files on right click?

Note: I have the `SideBarEnhancement` plugin installed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the default action for the side bar - if you click on a file (right-click or left) a preview will open up in the editor. To avoid this, open `Preferences -> Settings - User` and add

```json
"preview_on_click": false
```

to the file. Make sure to add a trailing comma if it's not the last entry in the list.

Another option is to ensure that certain file types are not displayed in the side bar. The defaults are:

```json
"file_exclude_patterns": ["*.pyc", "*.pyo", "*.exe", "*.dll", "*.obj","*.o", "*.a", "*.lib", "*.so", "*.dylib", "*.ncb", "*.sdf", "*.suo", "*.pdb", "*.idb", ".DS_Store", "*.class", "*.psd", "*.db", "*.sublime-workspace"]
```

but you can add additional values in your Preferences - just make sure you include everything that's there already, or it won't be excluded. For example, you could add `"*.pdf", "*.tif", "*.jpg"`, etc., depending on what type of files you encounter regularly.

Finally, you can exclude entire folders from being displayed - the defaults are:

```json
"folder_exclude_patterns": [".svn", ".git", ".hg", "CVS"]
```

so as to not display version control system directories, but you could just as easily add `"images"` for example if you do web development work.

Good luck!

Comment: thx, `preview_on_click` did the job. I thought there might also be something like `preview_on_right_click`but it appears there isn't

Comment: Glad I could help! For all the possible settings, go to `Preferences -> Settings - Default` and you can see all the possibilities, as well as short explanations of what they actually do. This file (in ST3) can't be edited, so anything you want to modify you'll need to copy to your `Settings - User` file and change there.

Comment: the `preview_on_click` is great but I'd like to set this per file type because while a PNG or JPG does preview correctly, an OmniGraffle file shoes up as a text file and I'd be afraid of corrupting it in the editor.

Comment: You can do something like: "preview_on_click": "only_left" now, works perfect